# Error: Unable to find method org.gradle.internal.logging.progress.DefaultProgressLoggerFactory.<init>(ProgressListener, TimeProvider)

Tags: java, android

I have got an error :

```
Gradle Sync Issues
Error:Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.internal.logging.progress.DefaultProgressLoggerFactory.<init>(Lorg/gradle/internal/logging/progress/ProgressListener;Lorg/gradle/internal/TimeProvider;)V'.
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I already try to updated Android IDE and gradle, but nothing changes.

Here my configuration :

- Android 3.0.1 (Also tried 3.1 Canary 4 Preview)
- Gradle 4.1.0
- Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Oracle JDK 8 to Oracle JDK 9 fixed this problem for me on Ubuntu 17.04, perhaps that might work on 16.04 too.

Comment: It seems that the latest update for android studio for linux is broken.  Google, please fix this.  The only work around is to download an older version from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html and edit the gradle files to target the older gradle api. A direct solution to the problem is Google fixing the obvious bug in the IDE.

Comment: @AndreGraveler Ok, sorry about this. I tried going back to JDK 8, and the error didn't come back, so I must have done something else for this to go away. I'll update if I find out what.